# Windows Terminal and (MinGW, Cygwin)

Tags: windows, cygwin, windows-terminal

It appears Microsoft are to introduce "Windows Terminal", see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/introducing-windows-terminal/
It appears that you will be able to programme in C.

I was thinking of installing either MinGW or Cygwin so that I could write some programmes in C. Will the introduction of Windows Terminal make these redundant?

Comment: For the record, you can program for Windows in C just fine without a terminal program. Check out [Visual Studio Comunity Edition](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/). If you want a create a command line program, feel free to specify "Console application" as the project type. And believe me, debugging with Visual Studio will be way, way easier than with terminal-based tools.

Comment: Upvoted.  The programming in C part of the question is a fine kettle of fish, but actually I think it has some merit.  These other tools exist for a reason.  At the moment, I need to use mintty and xterm from cygwin to manage the range of different programming environments that I use.  I've tried ConEMU to manage them, but its rather clunky.  Using this new Windows Terminal to connect a virtual tty through to the Cygwin and/or Msys2 shells such as zsh and bash, is a good Use case that I am interested in, and this is in addition to those advertised such as WSL and Windows Conhost etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Seva Alekseyev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/219159/seva-alekseyev) indicated, you don't need a terminal program to write C programs. You also don't need Cygwin or MinGW to write them. However, to answer the question that was asked, it appears that the new Windows Terminal will allow you to launch various shells. I'm hopeful that Cygwin will be among them. Note, however, that the new Windows Terminal appears that it will only work on the latest Windows 10 builds. In which case, you might consider WSL or even [WSL 2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/announcing-wsl-2/) (also slated for later this year), which probably will be a much better environment for you than Cygwin or MinGW.

Comment: Cygwin is not a shell it is a whole distribution of opensource software for unix-like operating systems. By default it uses bash as a shell. --- In many cases you can run C programs created for unix-like systems in Cygwin after recompiling them. Sometimes you have to modify them for Cygwin.

Answer (score 24):

As described in: https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/blob/master/doc/user-docs/ThirdPartyToolProfiles.md

Assuming that you've installed Cygwin into C:/Cygwin:

```
{
    "guid": "{916f2925-597a-4b52-aac2-9a4387626b4c}",
    "name" : "Cygwin",
    "commandline" : "C:/Cygwin/bin/bash --login -i",
    "icon" : "C:/Cygwin/Cygwin.ico",
    "startingDirectory" : "C:/Cygwin/bin" 
}
```

Note that the starting directory of Cygwin is set as it is to make the path work. The default directory opened when starting Cygwin will be `$HOME` because of the `--login` flag.

FYI: Following works on my PC using Cygwin64:

```
{
    "guid": "{379bd4d8-dc40-409a-abd4-3ff1712c12f7}",
    "name" : "Cygwin",
    "commandline" : "c:/cygwin64/bin/bash --login -i",
    "icon" : "c:/cygwin64/Cygwin.ico",
    "startingDirectory" : "c:/cygwin64/bin"
}
```

Comment: the guid is not mandatory : I do not use it.

Comment: @emmguyot you need the GUID if you want to set it as the default profile.

Comment: @AlexanderRevo The default profile can be set with the name
e.g :     "defaultProfile": "Cygwin"

Comment: @emmguyot I tried that before posting my comment, and got an error telling me "Check to make sure the "defaultProfile" matches the GUID of one of your profiles". But guess what - turns out you're right and the error message is wrong, the problem was that I typed `cygwin` instead of `Cygwin`, and apparently profile names are case-sensitive.

Comment: @AlexanderRevo Great that my comments helped you. You can use the "up arrow" to mark the comment useful

Comment: @emmguyot Already done ;)